# Problems in inserting data in mysql database using jsp and servlets?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am learning how to work with servlets and JSP in java. I tried to create a simple form and used the action method to post the data in a servlet to process it but for some reason the data is not inserted in the mysql database. I tried to check if the data is posted properly from the JSP form and it works perfectly. Then there is no sql error or anything but when i click on the submit button the data is not inserted in the mysql database. Can anyone please help me figure out the error. Here is my servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);
        String projectname = request.getParameter("projectname");
        String description = request.getParameter("description");
        String initiator = request.getParameter("initiator");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String repository = request.getParameter("repository");
        String projecttags = request.getParameter("tags");


        projecttags = projecttags.toLowerCase();
        String[] t = projecttags.split(",");
        int i;


         try {
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hactivism",
                         "root", "");
                 Statement st = con.createStatement();
                 //ResultSet rs;
                 for(int j=0;j<t.length;j++)
                 {  i = st.executeUpdate("insert into projectdetails(projectname, description, initiator,email,repository,projecttags) values ('" + projectname + "','" + description + "','" + initiator + "', '" + email + "', '" + repository + "', '" + t[j] + "'");

                     if (i > 0 && j==t.length-1) {
                         //session.setAttribute("userid", user);

                         response.sendRedirect("ProjectDescription.jsp");
                         // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
                     } else {
                         out.println("Registration Unsuccesful");
                     }

                 }       } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

  }
```

Comment: @Mechkov:- I actually use try catch block in my code.

Comment: Just saw it, try to indent properly next time.

Comment: @Mechkov:- Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you try catching just Exception, maybe there is something else happening?

Comment: @Mechkov:- I tried every way of doing it and there is no error that shows up. I have a feeling that the sql query might have some syntax problem. That's what my instincts say.

Comment: If so, there would be a SQLException

Comment: Do not output after (or before) a response.sendRedirect, immediately return. To the browser is sent that it should load the redirection page.

Comment: @Mechkov:- This line is what I think has syntax issues -                  {  i = st.executeUpdate("insert into projectdetails(projectname, description, initiator,email,repository,projecttags) values ('" + projectname + "','" + description + "','" + initiator + "', '" + email + "', '" + repository + "', '" + t[j] + "'");

Comment: Debug line by line and see what is happening, and make sure to close connection and statement object after use.